# Can I automatically add someone to a Civicrm group when the register as a WordPress subscriber?

Tags: wordpress, groups

When someone registers on our WP site I would like to automatically add them to a specific CiviCRM group.  I don't think a smart group would work here (if I could figure out the right search) because we want to use the group for emails and folks need to be able to unsubscribe.

Comment: Contacts can unsubscribe from smart groups, and you can also force contacts into smart groups so once you work out the search thats still an option. Another way to do this might be to use CiviRules but I'm not sure if they have an event for a new user in Wordpress yet.

Comment: The rule would be anyone who is a CMS user but not in any group would be in the smartgroup.  The problem with that is that folks who already unsubscribed and then became a user would then be put in the smartgroup and start getting email again.

Comment: Ok, maybe CiviRules is the way to go on this because you could check as part of the rule condition that they aren't part of any other group before adding them to the new group. I'm not sure if the new user condition exists but take a look and see what works. https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/basic-example-introduction/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a profile in CiviCRM to use for the Website registration form. Under Advanced Settings in the profile setup there are two things you want to do.

1. Add new contacts to a group. Here you can select the mailing list group. They will be added when they complete the profile.
2. Make WordPress account creation required.

After the form is complete they will have a WordPress account, be in your mailing group and have a contact record in CiviCRM. You can easily gather additional information about folks registering for your site.

Hope this helps!